# Automating matching system with google spreadsheet

Tags: python, data-science

I currently have a google spreadsheet in front of me filled with the data from multiple users. Does anyone know how I can match people up in this google spreadsheet based on having similar interests? If so, how would I import the data somehow and automate this matching system with python?

Comment: Thats a tall order there tex. You would basically be taking user input and comparing it to the "interests" from the field(s) in the spreadsheet. How do you plan to display matches? Why do you want to use python for this?

Comment: I want to use python for this because its the only language I know, but if there is a simple solution I will be up to try something else. And I don't know how I would display matches. The only time I've written code that gave an output, it was a piece of code I've written in sublime text and ran it on cmd.